# ffmpeg meets unknown timestamps error

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg concat to merge multiple ts files, I use following command

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy output.mkv
```

all ts files' path is put in filelist.txt, most of time it runs well, but when processing some ts files, ffmpeg gives following errors

```
[matroska @ 044bf9c0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[matroska @ 044bf9c0] Can't write packet with unknown timestamp
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

I guess the error is caused by those ts files missing timestamps? but since error message said "deprecated and will stop working **in the future**", so my question is ***Currently*** if there is a way or some ffmpeg command flags to suppress this error and just merge those ts files **without reencoding**, Thanks!

Comment: Output to MP4 and then remux that to MKV.

Comment: Thanks! Does that need reencoding? I want to do this job without reencoding

Comment: No re-encoding.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried, the file is merged, but "[mp4 @ 03e4eba0] pts has no value" this error message repeated a lot , Is it caused by timestamp error, Does it affect output file?

Comment: Most of the time, no.

Answer (score 0):

add `-fflags +genpts` to the ffmpeg command ie

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i foo.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy foo.mp4
```