# ffmpeg partially concat meets sample rate issue

Tags: ffmpeg, merge

I use ffmpeg concat to merge multiple ts files, I use following command

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy test.mkv
```

all ts files' path is put in filelist.txt, it runs well, but now my requirement changed, I want to merge those files partially, for example, the length of every file in filelist.txt is 1 minute, but I only want to merge first 7 seconds in every file, so I checked ffmpeg doc and use following setting in filelist.txt

```
file 'file1.ts'
inpoint 00:00:00.000
outpoint 00:00:07.000
file 'file2.ts'
inpoint 00:00:00.000
outpoint 00:00:07.000 
...
```

when running above command, ffmpeg gives following errors

```
 [matroska @ 03eb10a0] Error parsing AAC extradata, unable to determine samplerate.
    Error writing trailer of test.mkv: Invalid argumentframe=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
    video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
    Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

I guess the error is caused by those ts files (unable to determine samplerate?) rather than command line error, but my question is ***Currently*** if there is a way or some ffmpeg command flags to suppress this error and just merge those ts files **without reencoding**,or if source ts file contains samplerate problem, you just can not partially merge them, Thanks!

udpate: 
I tried my last question about ffmpeg's suggestion from Gyan([ffmpeg meets unknow timestamps error](https://superuser.com/questions/1384934/ffmpeg-meets-unknow-timestamps-error)), merge to mp4 but not mkv, strangely "Error parsing AAC extradata" error info really disappear, but still error : "Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)", Does that mean such source ts files can not be merged partially without re-encoding? Anyone else more suggestions?

Comment: Remove the inpoint lines and check.

Comment: @Gyan , Thanks for reply, you mean only write outpoint info after filename? I tried, but still the same error info